# Response [412] when using the requests python package to access this webpage, how to get around it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

This is the reproducible code:

```
import requests
url = 'http://wjw.hubei.gov.cn/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36'}
res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(res)
```

The code `print(res)` gives the following output:

`<Response [412]>`

I can open the webpage fine on my computer with Chrome.

Is there something missing in the header? Is there a way to get around the 412 error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no way to tell that. Web servers can return whatever status code they want for whatever reason. If you are able to access the site using a real web browser, try to imitate the same request by inspecting the headers using your browser's inspector.

Comment: @Selcuk That's what I did but with no luck. I understand that this could be not exactly a 412 error but it is annoying that while Chrome can open the webpage, the requests package cannot.

Comment: For the record, I am getting a 412 using Chrome, too.

Comment: @Selcuk May I know from which geographical location your are trying to open the webpage, USA?

Comment: @TerenceLam website will only response if you sent a cookie

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη Could you please show me how? I tried to add the cookie the header dict but didn't work.

Comment: @TerenceLam check my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

That website require a valid `Cookie` in order to response back to you.

I've tried several ways such as calling the main [website](http://www.hubei.gov.cn/) and then retrieving the `Cookie` under `requests.Session()` but the website is not allowing me to pass through.

So the only way which you can use as for now. Or to use `Selenium` or pass a valid `Cookie` to the `requests`

Here's how to get the `Cookie` and `User-Agent` via the browser:

[image]

Using the following Code:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0",
    "Cookie": "Hm_lvt_5544783ae3e1427d6972d9e77268f25d=1578572654; Hm_lpvt_5544783ae3e1427d6972d9e77268f25d=1578572671; dataHide2=64fa0f2a-a6aa-43b4-adf0-ce901e8d1a37; FSSBBIl1UgzbN7N80S=sXE0qXcyGkTm4uVerLqfZyUU3XFMZzkm22k.eqVABLPe0eYMo3D8uX5ZJ07.7cCr; FSSBBIl1UgzbN7N80T=4aY.P74ZFvDef6i1BgsPAGpjsGOCcIHJFaOyshl4_fJ1WvTk1nqBkdG9PsyX3VRZcIuI8zdYiRJw4rEBQfx.Mv.GS_wT6Hzgiw.AY.UMP.Mw4iCKXGDzY1UeIH2gUd15impxzBVzZpN3MnSdqD0TUqcxSq0RrvIuE8RKT5pFLAqaNnVqtbeSACx43yIYtKJ41y8Isu6a6lNOlWNeaFJ8bx22pKm3lAIO.HIDhGSZqrUP76.q3i4Iux59f7dqJPuSRF90G1LSUBE8t8HrlWzBcSwJJJARX4Ioc0iHmHvdkVoigUitTRjLUHJM4ieOV1sLBDsq"
}

r = requests.get("http://wjw.hubei.gov.cn/", headers=headers)
print(r)
```

Output:

```
<Response [200]>
```

[image]

Update:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"}

with requests.Session() as req:
    r = req.get("http://www.hubei.gov.cn/")
    headers['Cookie'] = r.headers.get("Set-Cookie")
    for item in range(10):
        new = req.get("http://wjw.hubei.gov.cn/", headers=headers)
        print(new)
```

[image]

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη Sorry, directly running the code you provided didnt work. I guess it is necessary to replace the '#pass_cookie_from_browser_here' part with a proper cookie string? Could you further elaborate?

Comment: Actually I notice that the cookie from browser kept changing whenever I refresh the webpage. And I used the cookie string from the browser and it still gives me the 412 error.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη Thanks for going to the trouble of posting code, however it still does not work for me on my end. This is strange. I copy and paste your code and it still gives me 412. Is it working for anyone else or is it just me?

Comment: @TerenceLam I've explained above that you need to pass your own `Cookie` from the browser during active session ! otherwise it's will not work.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη Argh, yeah I understand that but what I am trying to do is to write a tool to monitor this page on a regular interval. If I have to paste in the cookie from my browser every time I run the code then it is not very automatic... Am I missing something here? I cant believe there is no automatic way to get around it!

Comment: @TerenceLam I am _guessing that_ you should be able to capture the cookie returned with the first 412 response and re-submit that.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη Thanks for the new code, but again it still gives me 412 on my end. I tried it on different machines. One thing though, did u try a negative control? I mean did you try NOT submitting a cookie and see if you get a 200 or 412?

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks for the advice! Could you try  αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη's code and see if it works for you in your environment? It didnt work in my setting. Need to compare the mileage, thanks.

Comment: @TerenceLam if you still getting 412. so could you please tell me what's your `DNS`?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη I cannot access my usual router at this moment, but on a current machine with DNS set to 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8, it is still all 412 to me with your newer code. So did you try a negative control without sending a cookie? Hope the mileage is not so different at your end that you dont even need to send a cookie.

Comment: @TerenceLam whenever you set DNS on your local machine, the router will redirect you to it's own configured `DNS`. the website is requiring a valid `Cookie` to be sent in order to establish a connection. also be informed that the `Cookie` should be real because it's generated by the back-end script. with that said, you don't need to send `FAKE` `Cookie`. otherwise it's will keep respond back with `412`

Comment: `1.1.1.1` is related to `CloudFlare` but `8.8.8.8` is related to `Google` which will make a huge conflict. the correct one should be `8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205736/discussion-between--c-and-terencelam).

Answer (score -1):

import requests
response=requests.get("https://precog.iiit.ac.in/")
< Response [200] >

<Response [400]>

<Response [800]>

None of the above responses

Comment: The answer is not clear. Please modify your answer and add some explanation.